# Placing the right content into the right place

Tags: layout

I'm in the proccess of creating my own web profilo and personal website.
I have a layout and a design already done.
Now I have no idea where to place my content and how.
I have a layout like this:

### Menu

---

### Header

---

### Box 1 | Box 2 | Submenu

---

In the header I currently have "about me" information but I'm not sure it's the right place. Shouldn't the "about me" content be placed in the about me page?
Box 1 should be recent blog posts of that I am sure.
Box 2 might be the next pharagrap of the about me or maybe site news.
I am also not quite sure I need a sub menu in the index page but that section is empty if I don't have anything in it.
I have found [this webblog](http://www.alistapart.com/topics/content/writing/) a bit useful but I still want some advice on where to proceed ahead.

Comment: So this is the place for SEO but not for other marketing topics that are related to web design and layouting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that it's a good approach to write about yourself on a different page, not everyone is interested in your personality.

Standart solution is to place it as a last item of menu or at the bottom of the page like a footer. I think that placing it in menu would be better.

If you want another example of a good blog layout, I could point you to our famous blog by one of Stack Overflow creators - [Coding Horror](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/) by Jeff Atwood.

Comment: This is not just a blog but a web CV and a personal website.

Comment: Okay, but why does its idea of layout not suit your needs?